# responsive media queries in stylesheet not working

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design

My CSS isn't working on mobile portrait.

I want the main top menu to appear beneath the logo.

Here is my css at the mo:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
       #wrapper { 
         width:100%; 
       }
       #logo {
         margin-left: 100px;
       }
       #menu { 
         width:100%;
         display:inline-block; 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi now define your **wraper** `width 100%`  into `480px` as like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    #wrapper { width:480px; }

    #logo {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }

    #menu { width:100%;display:inline-block; }


}
```